# Совместимость std::string и std::vector<std::uint8_t>

Tags: c++, char, type-conversion

Есть небольшая проблема, связанная с преобразованием между байтами и символами. Я хочу избежать потенциальных **UB**, но не уверен, могут ли они произойти.

Данные читаются в `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` и затем с моей стороны должны быть разделены на две части: одна из которых всегда текстовая, а вторая либо текстовая, либо двоичная.

Есть некий делимитер, который я использую, например, так:

```
std::string delimiter{"delimiter"};

auto delim_iter = std::search(
    byte_vector.begin(), byte_vector.end(),
    delimiter.begin(),   delimiter.end()
);

delim_iter += delimiter.size();

std::string char_part{byte_vector.begin(),delim_iter};
```

Как известно, `char` в зависимотси от реализации может быть как `signed`, так и `unsigned`. Поэтому мне не понятно как правильно сделать, чтобы избежать проблем с этим.

При использовании, например, `std::transform` есть рекомендация передавать лямбду, которая принимает `unsigned char`:

```
std::transform(
    string.begin(), string.end(), string.begin(),
    [](unsigned char ch) { return std::tolower(ch); }
);
```

Могут ли здесь возникнуть какие-то потенциальные проблемы и можно ли их как-то решить? Спасибо.

Comment: Можно везде использовать uint8_t: `::std::array<::std::uint8_t, 9> delimiter{'d', 'e', 'l', 'i', 'm', 'i', 't', 'e', 'r'};`

Comment: @user7860670, для делимитера ОК, но как при этом поведет себя преобразовние из `unsigned char` в `char`, мне нужно вернуть `std::string`. Если в `std::string` будет использоваться знаковый `char`, то, настколько понимаю, будет UB для использования не `ASCII`. Если будет только `ASCII`, то по идее всё должно быть ОК. Думаю, возможно, стоит полагаться на это. Или все таки каст будет корректным и не для `ASCII`...  Ничего толкового не нашёл.

Comment: Для создания строки имеет смысл использовать конструктор `(char const *, size_t)`, который сделает memcpy, а не перебирающий итераторы.

Comment: @user7860670, хм, а это хорошая мысль. Спасибо)

Comment: @megorit, если в С++ стало столько UB, то может имеет смысл забыть его и использовать что-то получше?

Comment: @avp, в других языках свои проблемы. Плюсы развиваются и становятся лучше. Они будут и через сотню лет востребованы, а хайповые языки появляются и исчезают. Я уж молчю о производительности.

Comment: @megorit, вообще-то я имел в виду старый добрый Си

Comment: @avp, `если в С++ стало столько UB` Всё совсем наоборот же. Неопределённые поведения в языке активно доопределяются. Такими темпами, вполне возможно, что какой-нибудь C++52 даже вы начнёте рекомендовать к использованию наравне с Си ;)

Comment: @wololo, это вряд ли... Груз обратной совместимости сделает кресты (и так уже, говорят, что не найти человека, который знает **все** в С++) абсолютно неподъемной ношей. Лучше забыть о них (чем раньше, тем меньше будете страдать о напрасно прожитых годах)

Comment: @avp, Плюсы сложные, никто не спорит, но не неподъемные. К тому же нужно и другие языки осваивать. Я вот хочу Питон подучить. Можно и Плюсы ведь в Питон оборачивать. Довольно полезный навык =)

Comment: @megorit, блажен, кто верует. Язык нужен вам, чтобы максимально просто донести свои мысли до электронных схем компа (и других читателей вашей программы (людей, конечно же)). Если или вы будете путаться с языком (либо другие читатели), то ничего хорошего не будет. Вот теперь задумайтесь о мере сложности.

Comment: @avp, Честно. Если взять любую сишную либу и сравнить с плюсловой, то это небо и земля. Причём в большинстве сишных либ пытаются использовать ООП, умные указатели и прочее через костыли. А зачем?

Comment: @megorit, этим занимаются глупые люди, они зачем-то пытаются моделировать кресты (и вообще ООП). Не надо вообще смотреть на такие вещи. Надо решать конкретные задачи наиболее экономичным способом, строя абстракции (выражаемые в либах) не более, чем нужно для решения легко представляемых (а не любых воображаемых) задач такого-же типа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любой целочисленный тип может быть неявно преобразован в любой другой целочисленный тип.

1. Если целевой тип — `bool`, то нулевое значение преобразуется в `false`, любое ненулевое в `true`.
2. Если целевой тип — беззнаковый целочисленный тип, то значение преобразуется в целевой тип с использованием модулярной арифметики.
3. Если целевой тип — знаковый целочисленный тип, и преобразуемое значение представимо целевым типом, то оно не изменится при преобразовании. Если преобразуемое значение не представимо целевым типом, то

   - до C++20 результат преобразования определяется реализацией.
   - Начиная с C++20, значение преобразуется в целевой тип с использованием модулярной арифметики.

Начиная с C++20 можно быть уверенным, что

```
T1 v1 = ...;
T2 v2 = v1; //Поведение однозначно определено.
T3 v3 = v1; //Поведение однозначно определено.

v1 == v2; //Поведение однозначно определено, результат либо `true`, либо `false`.
T1(T2(v1)) == v1; //Поведение однозначно определено, результат `true`.
T3(v1) == T3(v2); //Поведение однозначно определено, результат `true`.
std::memcmp(&v1, &v2, 1) == 0; //Поведение однозначно определено, результат `true`.
```

где типы `T1`, `T2` и `T3` — это любые типы из следующего списка

`char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `std::int8_t`, `std::uint8_t`.

Приведённые утверждения следуют из свойств модулярной арифметики и использования для представления целочисленных типов [дополнительного кода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4).

До C++20 таких гарантий нет. В реализациях не использующих для представления знаковых целочисленных типов дополнительный код некоторые из приведённых утверждений определённо должны быть нарушены. Но столкнуться с такой реализацией  — это нужно очень сильно постараться. Обычно на практике приведённые утверждения выполняются.
Также до C++20, даже если всё-таки используется дополнительный код, стандарт всё равно отдаёт результат преобразования `(std::int8_t)255` на откуп реализациям. Тем не менее обычно наблюдаемое поведение соответствует C++20.

---

С учётом вышенаписанного имеем.

```
auto delim_iter = std::search(
    byte_vector.begin(), byte_vector.end(),
    delimiter.begin(),   delimiter.end()
);
```

Данный код не порождает неопределённого поведения. Но, т.к. функция `std::search()` для сравнения значений использует оператор `==`, то результат поиска может зависеть от того, является ли тип `char` знаковым или беззнаковым. [Пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/929fd0049db50ec4):

```
std::vector<std::uint8_t> delimiter_1 = {128};  //Имитируем беззнаковый char
std::vector<std::int8_t>  delimiter_2 = {-128}; //Имитируем    знаковый char
        
//Сравниваем вектора побайтово - они равны
cout << std::memcmp(&delimiter_1[0], &delimiter_2[0], sizeof(delimiter_1[0])) << endl; //0

std::vector<std::uint8_t> byte_vector = {128};

auto delim_iter_1 = std::search(
    byte_vector.begin(), byte_vector.end(),
    delimiter_1.begin(),   delimiter_1.end()
);
auto delim_iter_2 = std::search(
    byte_vector.begin(), byte_vector.end(),
    delimiter_2.begin(),   delimiter_2.end()
);

//Поиск с помощью std::search() даёт различные результаты
cout << (delim_iter_1 - byte_vector.begin()) << "  " << (delim_iter_2 - byte_vector.begin()) << endl; //0 1
```

Если нужно проверять на точное побайтовое соответствие, то можно использовать версию функции `search()`, принимающую бинарный предикат, в котором реализовать явное приведение аргументов к некоторому общему типу. Например, так:

```
auto is_equal {
    [](std::uint8_t a, char b) {return static_cast<unsigned char>(a) == static_cast<unsigned char>(b);}
};
```

---

Начиная с C++20 результат следующего кода однозначно определён:

```
std::string char_part{byte_vector.begin(),delim_iter};
```

Значения типа `std::uint8_t` будут преобразованы к типу `char`. Битовый паттерн при таком преобразовании не изменится, изменится способ его интерпретации. Обратное преобразование (`char` -> `std::uint8_t`) восстановит исходное значение.

До C++20 с большой вероятностью также будет работать.

---

Здесь

```
std::transform(
    string.begin(), string.end(), string.begin(),
    [](unsigned char ch) { return std::tolower(ch); }
);
```

при вызове лямбды будет происходит преобразование `char` в `unsigned char`. Затем при вызове `std::tolower()` будет происходить преобразование `unsigned char` в `int`.

Функция [`std::tolower()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) имеет параметр типа `int`. Однако, далеко не любое значение, представимое типом `int`, может быть передано в функцию `std::tolower()`. Аргумент должен быть либо равен `EOF`, либо должен быть представим типом `unsigned char`. В противном случае поведение функции не определено.

Т.к. передаётся значение типа `unsigned char`, то проблем быть не должно. Хотя стандарт допускает реализации в которых диапазон значений типа `unsigned char` шире, чем диапазон неотрицательных значений типа `int`. (Например, если `unsigned char` и `unsigned int` имеют одинаковое представление). Т.е. теоретически неопределённое поведение здесь возможно. Для собственного спокойствия я бы просто добавил проверку времени компиляции:

```
static_assert(
    std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max() <= 
    static_cast<unsigned int>(std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
);
```

Результат вызова `std::tolower()` имеет тип `int`. В стандарте не очень понятно описано, каков диапазон значений, возвращаемых данной функцией, но логично предположить, что это либо `EOF` (в том случае, если `EOF` будет передан в качестве аргумента), либо значение, представимое типом `unsigned char`.

Как и было сказано ранее, результат преобразования `unsigned char` в `char`, начиная с C++20, однозначно определён. В данном случае происходит преобразование `int` в `char`, но `int` хранит значение представимое `unsigned char`, поэтому результат эквивалентен.

Итоговая цепочка преобразований `char` -> `unsigned char` -> `int` -> `char`. В данном конкретном случае, если не учитывать реализации наподобие той, у которой типы `unsigned char` и `unsigned int` имеют одинаковое внутреннее представление, то проблем быть не должно.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto delim_iter = std::search(
    byte_vector.begin(), byte_vector.end(),
    delimiter.begin(),   delimiter.end(),
    [](const std::uint8_t lhs, const char rhs)
        { return (lhs == static_cast<std::uint8_t>(rhs)) }
);

delim_iter += delimiter.size();

std::string char_part;
char_part.reserve(std::distance(byte_vector.begin(),delim_iter));

std::transform(
    byte_vector.begin(), delim_iter, std::back_inserter(char_part),
    [](const std::uint8_t byte) { return static_cast<char>(byte); }
);
```